Why is my equation within a loop only calculated at the start of runtime
I have a simple script that takes the value of an IntValue instance and multiplies it according to a formula, the result is then attached to a vector3. When I run the game however, the equation is only calculated based on a preset value described in the IntValue instance and does not update. The vector3 is updated when running the debugger step-by-step buts does not update when the game is played. Can someone explain to me how to fix this issue?
Here is the code:
throttle = ship.Throttle.Value
thrust = (throttle * 1000) - 1000
thrust = thrust + 22000
ship.VectorForce.Force = Vector3.new(0, thrust, 0)
print(thrust) -- Optional for debugging


Where is the loop? You might need to show us more of your code so we can see where this sits in context of everything else.

Where exactly did you place this code? Is it part of a function? Or is it just like that in the script?

The code is inside of a function that is called using RunService every heartbeat.

For starters, I recommend checking not just thrust with a debug print, but also ship.VectorForce.Force and doing so both before and after the change attempt. I suspect this probably is changing ship.VectorForce.Force, but that something else is effectively changing it back. You need to verify 1) did the immediate change happen as expected & 2) did the change persist from one heartbeat to the next. It doesn't answer why or why not, but you need to first determine if the problem is in the code as shown or if it lies elsewhere.
